# Import JSON data into single cell in google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am wondering if anyone can give me an example on how to gather data from a JSON file, and import it into a single cell in google sheets? It does not need to be formatted or copied to multiple cells, it simply needs to take the entire contents of the JSON and copy it into a single cell. The file I am working with is also a local file. Can anyone shed some light? It does not necessarily need to use google apps script, if a python script or anything similar could do the same thing that would be ok

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Google Sheets cannot access your local files. It's a web application, so any external data it gets must be accessible from the Internet.

If your goal is simply to put the contents of a web-accessible JSON file in a single cell, the following [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) will do the job:

```
function import(url) {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
}
```

This simply grabs whatever page you point at, and crams its contents in a cell. Example: `=import("http://xkcd.com/info.0.json")`

---

If you do decide to parse JSON, be advised there isn't anything suitable built into Google Sheets at present. The project [importJSON by Trevor Lohrbeer](https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs) may be helpful.

Comment: I have the same question as the OP and have tried something similar to your `import()` function, but my API endpoint replied with `Google Apps Script not allowed`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an extension of "API CONNECTOR" for free in the google sheets and just paste the url of the json file you need to import.
here is the link to the API Connector extension
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/api_connector/95804724197
here is how to perform it.
https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/api-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31027935)